# Criteria Builder and OR creates "bad" SQL

Tags: jpa

I am attempting to recreate the following snippet of SQL using a Criteria Query:

```
SELECT t0.column1, 
       t0.column2 
  FROM SALES_TBL t1, 
       PRD t0
 WHERE (t0.column3 = '640420022' OR 
        t1.column4 = '640420022' OR 
        t1.column5 = '640420022' OR 
        t1.column6 = '640420022') AND
       t1.column7 = t0.column7
```

I am building a List of Predicates with the following:

```
preds.add(cb.or(cb.equal((Expression<?>) rootProd.get("prd"), ic.toUpperCase()),
                cb.equal((Expression<?>) rootProd.get("salesTbl").get("upc"), ic),
                cb.equal((Expression<?>) rootProd.get("salesTbl").get("salesCd"), ic),
                cb.equal((Expression<?>) rootProd.get("salesTbl").get("smisCd"), smis)));
```

But the actual SQL that is generated looks like this:

```
SELECT t0.column1,
       t0.column2
  FROM SALES_TBL t3,
       SALES_TBL t2,
       SALES_TBL t1,
       PRD t0
 WHERE ((((t0.column3 = '640420022') OR
          (t1.column4 = '640420022')) OR
          (t2.column5 = '640420022')) OR
       (t3.column6 = '640420022')) AND
       (((t1.column7 = t0.column7) AND
       (t2.column7 = t0.column7)) AND
       (t3.column7 = t0.column7)))
```

This query (with the actual column names obviously) takes approximately 10 minutes to return and when it does return there are 25 rows when only 1 is expected.

I am new to JPA and this one is driving me crazy.  How can I get JPA to produce the query at the top versus the one it is producing?

The only other course I seem to have open to me is to not us CriteriaBuilder.or and instead build the Predicate one at a time and merge the results into a List I can send back to the front end.  That just doesn't seem right though.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Greg

Comment: I may have found the answer to my own question.  I need to do some further testing but I changed the creation of the List of Predicates to using CriteriaBuilder.conjunction() and essentially manually building the specific portion of the WHERE clause.  I'll take any advice still if others have it and if my testing confirms this approach I'll add another comment with details.

Comment: I am apparently a victim of this bug, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=395792